# Can't enable shortcuts in gsconnect

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 23.10

I want to enable a keyboard shortcut for clipboard actions like pull and push but I can't do so. It is always showing "Already being used" . Can someone please help me with this.  I am using Ubuntu 23.10 .